# Date Validity and Leap Year Checker

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, math

I've been trying to find ways to shorten or modify this code to increase the efficiency and reduce the complexity. Any Help?

I'm new to this website so I hope for a good response :D!

```
a=int(input('Enter the date:'))
b=int(input('Enter the month:'))
c=int(input('Enter the year:'))
if b<=12 and a<=31 and b>0 and a>0:
    if b==2:
       if a>29:
           k=0
       elif a<=29:
           k=1
    elif b==1 or b==3 or b==5 or b==7 or b==8 or b==10 or b==12:
        if b>31:
            k=0
        else:
            k=1
    else:
        if b>30:
            k=0
        else:
            k=1
else:
    k=0

if k==0:
    print 'Invalid Date'

elif k==1:
    if (c%4)==0:
        if (c%100)==0:
            if (c%400)==0:
                t=1
            else:
                t=0
        else:
            t=1

    if t==1:
        print 'It is a leap year and has a valid date'
    elif t==0 :
        if a==29 and b==2:
            print 'It isn\'t a valid date neither a leap year'
        else:
            print 'It is a valid date and a leap year'
```

Comment: also its giving an error while running please help!

Comment: First suggested change: use meaningful variables names, e.g. `year`, `month` and `day` instead of `a`, `b` and `c`. (And yes, as per Vedang Mehta's answer, use built-in libraries for this...)

Comment: yeah , it gets complicated using such variables

Comment: What do you mean? Which variables? Surely it's more complicated trying to use variables with meaningless names.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right. Variable names should be self explanatory.

Comment: I meant using my variables such as `a` . Should've used meaningful ones instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inbuilt modules -

```
import datetime
import calendar


def validate_date(year, month, date):
    """Returns True if valid date else False"""
    try:
        datetime.datetime(year, month, date)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Use `calender.isleap(year)` to check if the `year` is a leap year or not.

Comment: the modules were helpful !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the built-in modules and roll your own code, and if you change `k` and `t` to logical variables you could use

```
k = (1 <= b <= 12) and (1 <= a <= [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][b])
t = (c%4 == 0) and (c%100 != 0 or c%400 == 0)
```

As recommended by others, you should also change your variable names to be more clear. Note that this does not test that the variables are integers.

Comment: thanks rory ,would use these in an exam :D . Vedang, it's just another way of doing it I guess

Comment: If this is a question asked in an exam, you must implement the solution like Rory did, otherwise in-built modules should be used.

Comment: @VedangMehta: Nothing is wrong with the built-in modules. I tried to imply that they would be better than my code, since they do more thorough parameter-checking. But sometimes a fellow wants to be able to do it on his own, for learning or for modifying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another easier and more efficient way to check whether the entered year is a leap year or not.

```
year = int(input("Type a year: ")) 

if year % 4 == 0 and year %100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:

    print ("\nIs a leap-year")

else:
    print ("\nIs not a leap-year")
```

Comment: oh yes, the logic had confused me.